# Problema al cargar Select Option HTML con List<T> Asp.Net Core

Tags: html, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Tengo una aplicacion Asp.Net Core donde desde mi controlador paso un model a mi vista, con ese modelo debo cargar datos en un Select Option HTML , pero mi metodo no esta cargando la data aunque el modelo que paso si contiene registros.

Puse un punto de interrupcion y dice :

Y no muestra error pero aun asi los elementos no se cargan, en la imagen se muestra que existen elementos pero no se agregan al select ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como puedo solucionar esto?

Mi Codigo:

```
@model List<Spartane.Web.Core.Models.InfoEmpresa>
 @{  string sep = "/";
     List<InfoEmpresa> Proveedor = new List<InfoEmpresa>();
     int n = 0;
     foreach (InfoEmpresa K in Model)
     {
         Proveedor.Insert(n, K);
         n++;
     } 
   }

    <div class="search_categories col-sm-3">
        <h7>Final Client</h7>
        <div class="select">
            <select name="FinalClient" id="FinalClient" class="Selector">
                @{ if (Proveedor.Count > 0)
                    {

                        int j = 0;
                        foreach (InfoEmpresa I in Proveedor)
                        {
                            <option value="@I.Id.ToString()@sep@j.ToString()">@I.Name</option>//AQUI EL ERROR
                            j++;
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <dv>No Data Found</dv>
                    }
                }
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: No entiendo porque si defines como model de la view un `List<Spartane.Web.Core.Models.InfoEmpresa>` debes hacer un `foreach` del Model para volcar los datos en la variable `Proveedor ` que es un `List<InfoEmpresa> `, eso no tiene ningun sentido. Podrias iterar directsmente el `Model` y generar el html

Comment: igual no lo carga ...

Comment: No aclaras mucho con solo decir que "no carga", si pones un breakpoint en el action del controller, se carga la lista? pones esta en el `return View(lista)` esa lista es la que cargas en el action

Comment: por supuesto que se carga la lista en la imagen del post se muestra un valor...fijate bien

Comment: si inspeccionas con el developer tools del browser el html generado no puedes los tag opcion? que pasa si quitas el `if` y solo dejas el `foreach` de los items de la lista, pero itera solo el Model

Comment: por supuesto que se carga la lista en la imagen del post se muestra un valor...fijate bien

Comment: pero solo te basas en que ves algo al inspeccionar el codigo, no usas otra tecnica mas que esa, estoy tratando de darte herramientas para que analices que sucede y mencionas siempre lo mismo, la imagen esta clara, pero debes analizar otros medio para descubrir que sucede, analiza el action, analiza el html generado en el browser, sino te quedas estancado

Comment: Por qué mejor no crear toda esa lógica en el controlador y luego pasarla a tu vista? recuerda el principio de MVC. No soy partidario de poner lógica en la vista, se hace difícil de mantener